# Consuming Webservice : Client application : C#

Tags: c#, wcf, soap, ws-security

Error:

> "System.ServiceModel.FaultException: InvalidSecurity : error in
>   processing the WS-Security security header"  ...

Could anyone help on this issue

```
   public void CallServiceMNB()
        {
            ServiceReference1.SOAPCLIENT objMNB = new ServiceReference1.SOAPCLIENT();
            ServiceReference1.SOAPCLIENTinput input = new ServiceReference1.SOAPCLIENTinput();
            string Username = "xxx";
            string Password = "xxxx";
            objMNB.ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName = Username;
            objMNB.ClientCredentials.UserName.Password = Password;
            input.p_FROM_DATE = "01-01-2018";
            input.p_JE_CATEGORY = "xxxx";
            input.p_GROUP_ID = "";
            input.p_JE_SOURCE = "YYYYYY";
            input.p_LEDGER_NAME = "YYYYY";
            input.p_TO_DATE = "31-12-2018";
            try
            {
                objMNB.Open();
                objMNB.GetGLDetails(input);
                objMNB.Close();
            }
            catch (Exception Ex)
            {
                this.richTextBox1.Text = Ex.ToString();
                objMNB.Close();
            }
        }


<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <startup> 
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1" />
    </startup>
    <system.serviceModel>
        <bindings>
            <customBinding>
                <binding name="YYYYYY">
                    <!--    WsdlImporter encountered unrecognized policy assertions in ServiceDescription 'http://gl.ws.apps.oracle.xxdof/':    -->
                    <!--    <wsdl:binding name='YYYYYY'>    -->
                    <!--        <sp:SupportingTokens xmlns:sp="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/07/securitypolicy">..</sp:SupportingTokens> -->




                    <textMessageEncoding messageVersion="Soap11" />
                    <httpsTransport />


                </binding>
            </customBinding>
        </bindings>
        <client>
            <endpoint address="https://XXXXX"
                binding="customBinding" bindingConfiguration="YYYYYY"
                contract="ServiceReference1.SOAPCLIENT" name="SOAPCLIENT" />
        </client>
    </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

Comment: yes Mr. Holterman... I provided the above-mentioned code and correct username and password!! I got the result in using SOAPUI(smartbear). In C# facing the security issue. Is any reference need to be added ??? kindly help

Comment: You are getting closer to an answerable question. It seems to be WCF, you should add that tag.

Comment: The complete exception text might help. And post the WCF configurations. The C# part looks OK but most WCF happens in app.config .

Comment: No Mr.Holterman. I am not using WCF just using a website to consume SOAP Webservice.

Comment: I see a lot of WCF though... And "WsdlImporter encountered unrecognized policy assertions" might be the start of your problems.

Comment: As a suggestion, consider using a BasicHttpBinding or WsHttpBinding with MessageSecurity. If SoapUI can talk to it the configuration can't be that exotic.

Comment: Thanks Mr.Holterman !! by using BasicHttpBinding in Appconfig thrown the same error but using WsHttpBinding it displays another issue :) ISSUE : "The content type text/xml; charset=utf-8 of the response message does not match the content type of the binding (application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8). If using a custom encoder, be sure that the IsContentTypeSupported method is implemented properly"

Answer (score 1):

The client credential depends on your SecurityBindingElement created in the Custom Binding hosting on the server.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.servicemodel.channels.securitybindingelement?view=netframework-4.7.2
You should add token to the security header in accordance with the authentication security mode of the Custom binding.
For the BasicHttpBinding, you need not to provide the credential by default, while we need to provide Windows account in Wshttpbinding by default.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/programming-wcf-security